# Change font color based on value retrieve from MySQL

Tags: php

I want the font to change its color at PHP based on value. its booking type value .. For example, Pending will change the font to Yellow, Approved to Green and Reject to Red.
[booking type font color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zT7Fo.png)

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('appointment') . " " . $this->lang->line('date'); ?></th>
        <!-- <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('opd') . " " . $this->lang->line('id'); ?></th>  -->
         
        
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('patient') . " " . $this->lang->line('name'); ?></th>
    
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('mobile_no'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('casualty'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('consultant') . " " . $this->lang->line('doctor'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('case'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('generated_by'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->lang->line('generted_time'); ?></th> 
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    
<?php
if (empty($resultlist)) {
?>
        <!-- <tr>
            <td colspan="12" class="text-danger text-center"><?php echo $this->lang->line('no_record_found'); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>  -->
<?php
} else {
    $count = 1;
    $total = 0;
    foreach ($resultlist as $report) {
        
        // echo "<pre>";
        // print_r($report['generated_by']);
        // echo die(); 
        
        if (!empty($report['amount'])) {
            $amount = $report['amount'] ;
            $total += $amount ;
        }
        $paymentmode = $report['payment_mode'];
      /*  if($report['payment_mode'] == 'paid'){
                $paymentmode =  $this->lang->line('paid');
            }else {
                $paymentmode = $report['payment_mode'];
        }*/

        if($report['paytype'] == 'visit'){
                $paymenttype =  $this->lang->line('visit');

        }elseif ($report['paytype'] == 'rechekup'){
                $paymenttype =  $this->lang->line('re_checkup');

        }elseif ($report['paytype'] == 'payment'){
                $paymenttype =  $this->lang->line('payment');

        }elseif ($report['paytype'] == 'bill'){
                $paymenttype =  $this->lang->line('bill');
        }
?>      
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo date($this->customlib->getSchoolDateFormat(true), strtotime($report['appointment_date'])) ?></td>
            <!--  <td><?php echo $report['id']; ?></td> -->
           
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/patient/profile/<?php echo $report['pid']; ?>"><?php echo $report['patient_name'] ?>
                </a>
            </td>
            
            <td><?php echo $report['mobileno']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo date('h:i a ', strtotime($report['casualty'])); ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $report['name']." ".$report['surname']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $report['case_type'];?>
           
       
           
           </td>
            
<?php
        
    $this->db->select('name');
    $this->db->from('staff');
    $this->db->where('id', $report['generated_by']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $generated_by = $query->row();
                                            
?>
            <td><?php echo $generated_by->name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $report['created_at'] ; ?></td>
        </tr>
<?php
    $count++;
}
?>

        
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

"  " its booking type value .. what i need to change its color at PHP based on value. its booking type value .. For example, Pending will change the font to Yellow, Approved to Green and Reject to Red

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Why not add the value as a class to the `td` element and use CSS to change the color based on that? It appears you have control over the markup the PHP outputs.

Answer (score 0):

use css classes

```
<style>
    .approved {
        color: green;
    }
    
    .rejected {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

add class to you div by php

```
<div class="<?php echo $status ?>" >... </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: explain more because not working

Comment: after adding css

Comment: what should i type here  <td><?php echo $report['case_type'] ;?>

Comment: i think " if else" condition